# HTTP Request from browser, is it logged?

Tags: javascript, http, console, fetch

if I will run http request via fetch to **website A** from chrome console on **website B**, will the **website B** log any part of that request or is that request completely client side (browser side)? Simple question - can the **website B** know?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you request a ressource of the internet the server from the requested ressource will know there was a request. If it is logged depends on the settings if the server, but most likely yes

Comment: The server on which site B is running will know everything

Comment: not sure If i got you right but I am asking if the website server **where** I do the request from **browser console** can see it

Comment: No, website B will not know that you issued a request to site A from the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

In principle the site you are on and from where you do something in the console will not know what you do.

However they COULD trigger a request to the server for ALL requests on the page

Try running this and then do some ajax in the console, for example a $.get

```js
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSend handler." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="log"></span>
```